# Modelbuilder - iterate consecutive workspaces and select specific rasters from each

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select, iteration, wildcard

This is probably easiest explained with a picture,

[image]

I'm trying to iteratively perform a calculation using specific rasters from each two consecutive folders in a folder. For example from above picture, Iterate through the Date Folders in the Year Folder, and select the *B4.TIF* from date 1 and date 2, then process using these two tifs.

I can parse and slice filenames for the output files and folders, however just cannot figure out how to selectively iterate?

Have tried to parse filename and slice/calculate value for an inline variable based on each date to use as a wildcard but I'm just getting rasters from the last folder in the list.

I know using python would be easier, but I don't have the skills hence the post!

Comment: I doubt it is possible using Modelbuilder. Do you have enough python skill to post a code attempt and you will get the help you need to make it work? See for example this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it is possible using Model Builder. So this is one Python way to do it which you are not asking for. I can delete the answer if you want. Change root folder and out folder and it should work. You can execute it in the Python window. I don't have Spatial Analyst so I have not tested it fully.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import tee, izip

root_folder = r'C:\Test\Root_folder'
out_folder = r'C:\Test\outfolder'
file_ending_to_select = 'B4.TIF'

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

d = defaultdict(list)

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(file_ending_to_select):
            d[subdir.split('\\')[-2]].append(os.path.join(subdir,file))

print 'Defaultdict is: ', d

for year, rasters in d.iteritems():
    for y1, y2 in pairwise(rasters):
        #For this line to work the file name need to look like in your screenshot:
        foldername = '{0}-{1}'.format(os.path.basename(y1).split('_')[-5], os.path.basename(y2).split('_')[-5])
        newfolder = os.path.join(out_folder, foldername)
        os.makedirs(newfolder)
        outMinus = Minus(y1, y2)
        outMinus.save(os.path.join(newfolder,'{0}.tif'.format(foldername)))
```

Comment: that's programming for me, as frustrating as it is promising. I'm copying the scipt into the Python window in Arc, hitting enter and nothing happens! I will do some reading and see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: @Grasshopper: Have you changed root_folder and out_folder? I have changed the script to look for files ending with B4.TIF instead of B4.tif and added a print statement. What gets printed out?

Comment: That worked, wow. I think I was not entering the folder directories correctly. Ran very quickly too. I might be inspired to figure out what this script is doing. Thanks! One other thing, is it possible to have the Result.tif named the same as the output folder?

Comment: @Grasshopper yes try again. Try to research os.walk, collections.defaultdict, and how to manipulate strings using format,  split, and indexing (like [-5]).